# Copying and Concating Two Textfields to another in Drupal Webforms

Tags: drupal-7

I am having two Selects as Type and Category. The third is a textfield named `Index`. The values for Type is `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and Category is `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`.

I would like to get automatically the value in Index as `4A` or `1E` as the case may be as selected by user.

Comment: You should post the code what you tried. Visit our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I tried out this and its working, You can do this using hook_form_alter, #after_build and jQuery.

First of all create your webform with desired fields.
Then create a custom module and use hook_form_alter, I am adding a sample code below, you just need to replace "hook" with your module name and "your_webform_id" with your webform id.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    //to check your webform id.
    //drupal_set_message($form_id);

    if($form_id == "your_webform_id"){
        $form['#after_build'] = array('_webform_after_build_handler');
    }
}

function _webform_after_build_handler(&$form, &$form_state){
    //*change the webform field id's as per your form*

    drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    var typ = jQuery("#edit-submitted-type").val();
    var cat = jQuery("#edit-submitted-category").val();
    if(cat != "" && typ != ""){
            jQuery("#edit-submitted-index").val(typ + cat);
        }
    jQuery("#edit-submitted-category").change(function(e){
        var typ = jQuery("#edit-submitted-type").val();
        var cat = jQuery(this).val();
        if(cat != "" && typ != ""){
            jQuery("#edit-submitted-index").val(typ + cat);
        }
    });
    jQuery("#edit-submitted-type").change(function(e){
        var typ = jQuery(this).val();
        var cat = jQuery("#edit-submitted-category").val();
        if(cat != "" && typ != ""){
            jQuery("#edit-submitted-index").val(typ + cat);
        }
    });', 'inline');
    return $form;
}
```

Hope this will help you.